# How do I use the PHP foreach() function?

Tags: php, foreach

I have this situation: multiple option names and multiple option values. How do I display foreach option name all the values?

My code does this:

```
Roses (option name) are red (option value)
Roses are blue
Roses are white
```

How I want it to display like this:

```
Roses are red, blue, white
```

Here's my current code:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
        - <small>
        <?php echo $option['name']; ?> 
        are 
        <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small><br />
        
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is `$option['value']` an array of color?

Comment: Can you put a little example of you array?

Comment: you are looking for "for(;;;)" not "foreach();"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, you could do:

```
Roses are
```

```
<?php
    foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
        echo "$option['value'], ";
    }
?>
```

(Maybe change the change 'Roses', but I don't know where this name would be in you code.)

Answer (score 0):

Just store the `$option['name']` and test if it's the same as the previous iteration:

```
<?php
    $previous = null;
    foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
        if ($option['name'] == $previous) {
            echo ", {$option['value']}";
        }
        else {
            if ($previous)
                echo "</small><br/>";
        ?>
        - <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?> are
        <?php echo $option['value'];
        }
        $previous = $option['name'];
    }
    echo "</small><br/>"; ?>
```

My code is a bit messy and not tested, but I guess you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option.

Your initial array (this is probably grabbed from a database. I'm kind of guessing the exact structure based on your question, but should be close):

```
/* Initial array
Array
(
    [option] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Roses
                    [value] => red
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Violets
                    [value] => blue
                )
            [ ... ]
        )
)
*/
```

Loop through it and make it into an array with each value holding an array of colors. Basically grouping `$value`s on their `$name`. This is pretty handy also because it doesn't matter if your database entries are out of order.

```
// Loop all $product['option']
foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {

    // If we don't have an array made for this $name, make one
    if (!is_array( $products[ $option['name'] ] ) )
        $products[ $option['name'] ] = array();

    // Add the $value to the $name's array
    $products[ $option['name'] ][] = $option['value'];
}

/* $products = 
Array
(
    [Roses] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
            [1] => blue
            [2] => white
        )

    [Violets] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => white
        )

)
*/
```

Next it's just a matter of sentence structure, combining it all together. Since you have a handy array, you can also do a multitude of other forms of output quickly - this is just for your sentence question.

```
// Loop the new array of name=>array(vals)
foreach($products as $name => $value){

    // Counter variables and initial values for output
    $cnt = count($value);
    $cur = 2;
    $out = $name . " are ";

    // Loop all $values for the current $name 
    foreach($value as $v){

        // Make the output
        $sep = ($cur > $cnt ? "."
            : ($cnt == 2 || $cur == $cnt ? " and " : ", ") );
        $out .= $v . $sep;
        $cur++;
    }
    // Save the output to the name array
    $products[$name]["out"] = $out;
}
```

This output can be used now anywhere you can access the `$products` array

```
echo $products["Roses"]["out"];
echo $products["Violets"]["out"];

/*
Output:
Roses are red, blue and white.
Violets are blue and white.
*/
```

http://codepad.org/sL8YhzCq